# How can I insert multiple entries into a table with a select?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
INSERT INTO DM_SPONSOR_EQUIPO_VENTA dsev (dsev.SEV_IDEQUIPO_VENTA, dsev.SEV_IDSPONSOR)
VALUES (:id,
        (SELECT ds.SPO_IDSPONSOR  
         FROM DM_SPONSOR ds
         INNER JOIN DM_GRUPO dg ON ds.GP_IDGRUPO = dg.GP_IDGRUPO
         WHERE dg.GP_IDGRUPO = :idg))
```

Where `:id` is static and the second row is a multiple data inputs that the select returns?

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5600 |
| 1 | 83000 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
insert into dm_sponsor_equipo_venta (column_a, column_b)
select :id, ds.spo_idsponsor
from dm_sponsor ds inner join dm_grupo dg on ds.gp_idgrupo = dg.gp_idgrupo
where dg.gp_idgrupo = :idg;
```